# css only, show div only first time page is visited

Tags: html, css

I have set some divs named `#a1`, `#a2` ... `#a100`

I need to hide and show divs based on links. Problem is that original div (`#a1`) always is shown.

It kind of works, fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1ethjztf/2/)

Code:

```
 #a1 {
    display:block;
}
div:not(:target) {
    display: none
}
div(:target) {
    display: block
}
```

How can I get rid of it after selecting another `div`?

No JavaScript is possible as it's for an ebook reader and it doesn't execute JS.

Comment: use the TidyUp function of jsFiddle, it works wonders for readability

Comment: thanks, applied tidy up

Comment: Then you should also see the red tags. Meaning that your HTML structure misses some closing tags... Could you please provide the *right* HTML code...

Comment: This 'thing' isnt working at all, First off all when you load the page you dont see div 3... Then when you click on a link you see 3 but 1 is still there. For as war as i know you need javascript

Comment: are you able to control how the user visits the page? if the user is clicking a link to get to this page, you could have the link go to `index.html#a1` instead of just `index.html` (for example).

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow I can't, there's a single page displayed (as far as I know), thanks a lot for the suggestion tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this help you?
https://jsfiddle.net/1ethjztf/12/

```
<a name="1" href="#a1">1</a> 
<a name="2" href="#a2">2</a> 
<a name="3" href="#a3">3</a> 
<a name="4" href="#a4">4</a> 

<div id="a1" class="hide-not-target">
    <h1>1</h1>
    <p>1st content<br/>
    with some more stuff<br/>
    and some more stuff</p>
</div>

<div id="a2" class="hide-not-target">
    <h1>2</h1>
    <p>2nd</p>
</div>

<div id="a3" class="hide-not-target">
    <h1>3</h1>
    <p>3rd</p>
</div>

<div id="a4" class="hide-not-target">
    <h1>4</h1>
    <p>4th content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, is there a way to show number 1 by default or user must click it necessarily?

Comment: `#a1{
    display:block;
}` would work, but it will always be visible

Comment: Thanks, I will go with a link to the first page.

Answer (score 2):

This solution isn't perfect, but it does allow you to have the first div showing by default. It works by always showing the first div, and showing the other divs on top of the first one only when selected. Depending on how dynamic your content is, this might cause problems with bleeding edges if you aren't able to explicitly define position or size.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qdh453nx/)

```css
div(:target) {
    display:block;
}

div:not(:target) {
    display:none;
}

div {
    position: absolute; /* so that the divs will be layered */
    top:40px; /* they all need to be in the same place */
    left: 10px;
    background-color: #fff; /* they need some sort of background */
    height: 100px;
}

#a1 {
    display: block !important; /* make the first one always visible */
}
```

```html
<a href="#a1">Section 1</a> | <a href="#a2">Section 2</a> | <a href="#a3">Section 3</a>

<div id="a1">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor set amet.</p>
</div>

<div id="a2">
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <p>This has more text.</p>
</div>

<div id="a3">
    <h3>Section 3</h3>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, unfortunately the content is not set to a predefined height so some overlap does occur.